# RESTFul XML Service sending (401) Unauthorized Error

Tags: c#, .net, xml, rest, cookiecontainer

I've been trying to use a RESTful XML service that brings back extra data on a search using names or last names. The way I am suppose to authenticate is by using a separate REST API request that gives me access to the rest of the services. But by the time I call the second request it sends me the following error. "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.". The user and password that I'm using are the correct ones so I'm a bit stuck on why this message is being sent.

```
using System.Net; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Xml; 
using System.Xml.XPath;

private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string sURL, aURL;
    sURL = "http://url.com/data/qws/access?var1=user&var2=password";
    aURL = "http://url.mx/data/qws/pepsp?name=miguel&lastname=osorio";

    CookieContainer cookieQ = new CookieContainer(); 
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sURL);
    request.CookieContainer = cookieQ;

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(aURL);
    request.CookieContainer = cookieQ;
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    using (response) {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
        XmlNode name = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/xml/person/name");
        XmlNode lastname = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/xml/person/lastname");
        MessageBox.Show(name.InnerText + ' ' + lastname.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the response cookies to the second request cookies so that authorization cookies are presented.

Comment: WIthout knowing how the service works nobody can help you, pr example, maybe the first service is returning you a token which you must use on headers, so the cookies will do anything, or maybe it authenticates in another way. You need the service's description. Try to ask to the provider if it has a swagger interface to check the service's functionality